# How to identify when Amazon EC2 Windows instance is online after a reboot

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-ec2

I am trying to write a script to patch Windows EC2 instances and after installing the patches a reboot is required.

I can code to reboot the instance but how to identify whether whether server is back online or not?

I am talking about Windows Instances and I have tried with `get-ec2instancestatus` cmdlet but no use.

Comment: Are you performing restart with Windows command or using AWS CLI? You can use  Restart-EC2Instance command in AWS Windows PowerShell Tool and then check the "InstanceState" with Get-EC2InstanceStatus.

Comment: A reboot takes place at the Operating System level. As far as Amazon EC2 is concerned, the virtual machine is running just like normal, so it cannot tell you when the OS is doing. You would need to connect to Windows somehow to see whether it is responsive. What do you intend doing once the instance is available again?

Comment: Are you aware of [AWS Systems Manager Patch Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/mt/patching-your-windows-ec2-instances-using-aws-systems-manager-patch-manager/)? Might you could use this service instead of scripting your own thing :-)

Comment: @John Rotenstein - I have windows instances in scaling group and want to suspend the health check process before initiating a reboot of the server to mitigate the risk of getting terminated and once server is back online available for RDP, I would need to remove the health check process from suspended process for the scaling group..

Comment: @Patrick - I am using the SSM to perform the patching... but SSM will not help me in restarting the server without terminating it if I dont suspend health check process for the scaling group... :)

Comment: @Jeevagan - Yes.. I have already your suggestion but taht won't help.. As John mentioned, AWS won't detect the stauts of OS layer.. for AWS, it is always running until you terminate it :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are launching instances via Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling and you wish to perform an operation on newly-launched instances before the join the Auto Scaling group, you can use [Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling Lifecycle Hooks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/lifecycle-hooks.html).

When Auto Scaling launches an instance, it puts the instance into a '**wait state**', calls the lifecycle hook, then waits for a signal. Once the signal is received, the instance is placed into the Auto Scaling group and health checks commence.

**Your code** will be responsible for responding to the signal from the lifecycle hook, updating the instance as desired, then signalling that the process can continue.

Comment: Thanks for the response John but I think my question was not clear.. let me put it here in other words.. I have a Windows EC2 instance and ICMP is not enabled so ping is not option to check whether OS is up or not.. now, if I reboot this server remotely using restart-ec2instance cmdlet, How can I trace whether the reboot is completed and server is back online for RDP? since ping won't get a reponse what other options we have?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear... My answer is suggesting an alternative process rather how to answer your stated question. Using a Lifecycle Hook avoids the need to suspend the Health Check, so it is a "cleaner" approach to configuring servers before they start serving traffic in an Auto Scaling group.